# Android, error after 3-4 runs

Tags: android

I am a noob learning Android and making my own little demo project at the same time.

Basically, when the user starts my app it shows levels.java with 8 buttons, when the user clicks the 8th button this fires:

```
public void button_clicked8(View v) {
        text1.setText("clicked 8");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GameScreen.class));
}
```

which starts my main `gamescreen` class where the simple game is played.

If the user gets the math problem wrong 3 times, the game is over and I fire this code:

```
r_settings.setGameStarted(false);
        r_settings.setGameOver(0);
        r_settings.setInternalLevel(0);
        r_settings.setDisplayLevel(0);

        this.finish();
```

which basically resets some static variables and sends the user back to the levels.java screen.

So far all of the above works like a charm, in the levels screen if the user presses the 8 button again the game starts again, the problem is this works for around 4 times, on the 4th or 5th time it goes to the gamescreen but nothing works... and then in logcat I get this error:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/68081548.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/93717315.png/
(you need to click the image to see it full size)

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!
R

Comment: perhaps showing us line 64 of your GameScreen class with help finding the problem ;)

Comment: Hehe Added the offending line in Blackriders response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you get a NullPointerException at GameScreen.java:64. Does it work after you fix that?

Comment: Heh! I did say I was a noob :) this is at line 64:`
soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);`

Comment: Either soundPool or soundPoolMap is null. Fix that and you'll be good :)

Comment: Ok, will check, but any idea why it works like 3-5 times and then suddenly throws that error?

Comment: if you are using audio player of some kind - be sure to call audioPlayer.release() before finishing the activity in case the audio was playing then. Also it's a poor design to change these variables and afterwards call activity.finish() in a method other than finish. You'll be better off overriding the finish() method ;)

Comment: Thanks iLate, will take your advise as well!  Cheers!